# PowerBI how to calculate KPI based column value in DAX formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate a KPI in DAX formula with 3 different behavior based on specific column value.

In the below image I've highlighted in green the portion of table created on my pbix and in orange the desired KPI calculate in DAX. For your convenience I've added an explanation of KPI's formula.

[image]

In detail, the standard formula for KPI is the ratio between **nAswers** on **nCalls** but we have 3 different behavior based on **Player** column:

- if player contains the string "OUT" then formula is **nAswers/nCalls**
- if player contains the string "IN" then formula is "null value (or blank)"
- if player is equal to "All" then formula is **nAswers(minus nAswers of IN) /nCalls (minus nCalls of IN)**

At the moment my DAX formula calculate KPI for OUT and IN player

```
KPI = 
VAR _num = 
CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[nAswers]);
    FILTER('Table';AND(RIGHT('Table'[Player];2)<>"IN";'Table'[Player]<>"All")))
VAR _den = 
CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[nCalls]);
    FILTER('Table';AND(RIGHT('Table'[Player];2)<>"IN";'Table'[Player]<>"All")))
RETURN  IF(NOT(ISBLANK(_num));(_num/_den);BLANK())
```

And the related result is

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Adriano, the question is clear. However, I wonder why you need a single KPI to use different logic. How the final user would be aware that depending on a different column the KPI is calculated differently, hence, causing a lot of confusion. What do you think?

Comment: Hi @Seymour, thanks for your reply but the KPI that I need to implement is meaningful for OUT-type of Player. In detail, player is a list of CallCenter: IN (internal to the organization) and OUT (thirdy parties). KPI measure only performance related to OUT players. In addition when Player is equal to "All" means that "nCalls" and "nAswers" columns are the sum for IN and OUT value for each day. But KPI for player "All", shouldn't be calculate simply as nAswers/nCalls but we need consider the total nAswer and total nCalls for only OUT players. Final users are aware. I hope to have clarified all